# How to return a stored procedure as a string in C# code and ALTER it partially

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, alter, dataadapter

I want to change a part of a stored procedure in C# code. It would be great if someone can offer a solution how to do that with DataAdapter.
So, basically, I need to return the store procedure from database as a string so than I can replace a part of that string and finally execute it. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can't imagine why you want to do this, or if you would why you want a `DataAdapter` and not just do `ExecuteScalar`, but take a look at `select * from sys.procedures`

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to modify the data returned by the stored procedure, or are you trying to modify the stored procedure itself? If you can explain more about what you're hoping to accomplish, we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: This is an temporary solution I need to have to make a workaround due to an bug related to it. I'm trying to modify the stored procedure itself. So, to simplify,  I just need to store into variable whole existing stored procedure as a string in C# code and then I guess it will be simple to replace what is needed and execute it. I'm using DataAdapter generally in the project so that is why I would prefer it but I don't have to use DataAdapter exactly.

Comment: And to clarify further. I'm using DataAdapter for executing some stored procedures but I had no need so far to alter a part of it in the code. So, actually I need to get the current stored procedure, change a part of it and execute it after that change. So, my idea is to get it as a string and replace what needed and than execute it. Thanks for your answers I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: @Eyeball just tagging you.

Comment: If you already have the database permissions necessary to modify the SPROC, couldn't you just make your changes directly through SSMS? Just trying to make sure there aren't easier options here.

Comment: @Eyeball Well, I need to change SP with every build. Alternative is to do it manually every time with new build. That change would be actually workaround for an bug, so it will be temporarily.

Comment: @Eyeball I will try to do something with                      
      DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(i2iConnectionString);
      adapter.SetSqlStringCommand(String.Format(@"sp_helptext '[storedProcedureName]'"));
DataSet set = adapter.GetDataSet();
DataRowCollection collection = set.Tables[0].Rows;         Then I can read every SQL statement from SP row by row. So, I can store it in a new variable and do some replacing where needed. But, I'm not sure that this is a good way.